# Gmail BCC by cell value

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, google-apps-script

I want to send an email with bcc option.
Email works fine but I cannot use bcc.

How can I send a bcc with the info given from a range or cell value?

See my code below

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
        bcc: 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
       // attachments: [blobs[i]], kmlijst
       attachments: [blobs[i], kmlijst.next()]
      });
```

bcc: 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' has to be a cell vallue from

```
      var emailRange2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Lees_deze_informatie").getRange("d3");
var emailAddress2 = emailRange.getValues();
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please clarify what you have tried to read the cell value from the spreadsheet and use it as the bcc recipient.

Answer (score 0):

You are extracting the value from a single cell (D3), so you would use `getValue()`.

**DELETE:**
`var emailAddress2 = emailRange.getValues();`

**SUBSTITUTE:**
`var emailAddress2 = emailRange.getValue();`